# FIrst and last data for multiple nights for multiple factors

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

I have a list of bat calls that have been recorded over multiple night.  Multiple species have been recorded.  I want to pull out the first and last call (from sunset to sunrise rather than by day c. 19:00 - 07:00) for each species for every day.  I then need to calculate the time after sunset and before sunrise for each first and last call.  I have put an example of the data below.

[image: data]

Comment: What you have you done so far to solve the problem? The last two lines of your table show differing dates. You will have to explain that.

Comment: Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: Did you want to return the first and latest time in the same day for different species?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the last two rows have different dates as it was the night of 21st but the time was after midnight.  With this in mind column C will be the one to look at for the date.

For sort order I'm assuming it's sorted by column A and then B so the times are in chronological order.

- Column F has a unique list of species:
  `=SORT(UNIQUE($D$2:$D$31))`
- Column G looks for the first entry of a species on the date in `G1`:
  `=XLOOKUP($F3 & G$1,$D$2:$D$31 & $C$2:$C$31,$B$2:$B$31,,,1)`
- Column H looks for the last entry of a species on the date in `G1` (note the -1 as the search mode):
  `=XLOOKUP($F3 & G$1,$D$2:$D$31 & $C$2:$C$31,$B$2:$B$31,,,-1)`

[image]